# Not showing any solution in cplex

Tags: node.js, cplex, solution, docplex, docplexcloud

CPLEX is not showing any solution after I have integrated the equations of pevch[i][j] and pevdis[i][j]

> int t=24;
> int n=10;
> int j=0;
> range number =1..n;
> range tavail=1..t;
> float soc[number][tavail]=...;
> //forcasted load at 0..4
> float pl[tavail]=[10000000,7000000,9000000,6000000,12000000,6000000,4000000,15000000,9000000,12000000,6000000,8000000,10000000,7000000,9000000,6000000,12000000,6000000,4000000,15000000,9000000,12000000,6000000,8000000];
> //soc of ev at 0..11
> //generation
> float pg[tavail]=[10000000,9500000,8500000,11000000,600000,7500000,10000000,9500000,8500000,11000000,600000,7500000,10000000,9500000,8500000,11000000,600000,7500000,10000000,9500000,8500000,11000000,600000,7500000];
> //target load at 0..11
> float pt[tavail]=[10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000];
> //bus voltage at 0..11
> float v[tavail]=[240,232,229,233,230,235,228,234,227,229,231,230,226,232,233,230,236,233,231,232,232,233,233,230];
> //bus voltage at
> target bus voltage at 0..11
> float vt[tavail]=[230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230];
> //decision variable charging power ev
> dvar float pevch[tavail][number] in 0..100000;
> //decision variable discharging power of ev
> dvar float pevdis[tavail][number] in 0..100000;
> //objective function
> minimize sum(i in tavail)((pt[i]-pl[i])+sum(j in number)-pevch[i][j]+sum(j in number)pevdis[i][j]);
> subject to
>
> forall(i in tavail,j in number)
> if(pt[i]-pl[i]<0 && soc[j][i]>0.7&& v[i]<vt[i])
> pevch[i][j]==(0.9-soc[j][i])*100000/(24-i);
> else
> pevdis[i][j]==0;
>
> forall(i in tavail,j in number)
> if(pt[i]-pl[i]>0 && soc[j][i]<=0.7 && v[i]>vt[i])
> pevch[i][j]==(0.7-soc[j][i])*100000/(24-i);
> else
> pevch[i][j]==0;
> }

Answer (score 0):

if you name your constraints cplex will provide relaxations that should help you debug your model.

You can change

```
forall(i in tavail,j in number) if(pt[i]-pl[i]<0 && soc[j][i]>0.7&& v[i]<vt[i]) pevch[i][j]==(0.9-soc[j][i])*100000/(24-i); else pevdis[i][j]==0;

    forall(i in tavail,j in number) if(pt[i]-pl[i]>0 && soc[j][i]<=0.7 && v[i]>vt[i]) pevch[i][j]==(0.7-soc[j][i])*100000/(24-i); else pevch[i][j]==0; }
```

into

```
forall(i in tavail,j in number) ct1:if(pt[i]-pl[i]<0 && soc[j][i]>0.7&& v[i]<vt[i]) pevch[i][j]==(0.9-soc[j][i])*100000/(24-i); else pevdis[i][j]==0;

    forall(i in tavail,j in number) ct2:if(pt[i]-pl[i]>0 && soc[j][i]<=0.7 && v[i]>vt[i]) pevch[i][j]==(0.7-soc[j][i])*100000/(24-i); else pevch[i][j]==0; }
```